# Rails 3 using fields_for in view doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement master detail in a rails form with fields_for.

I have one model called Recipe:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :directions, :presence => true

  has_many :recipe_ingredients 
end
```

and one model called RecipeIngredient:

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  #belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

In the new controller I populate the ingredients with three empty records like this:

```
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    3.times {@recipe.recipe_ingredients.build}
    # @ingredients = RecipeIngredient.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @recipe }
    end
  end
```

What I would like to do in the view is to output the recipes fields (which works ok) and the three fields for recipe ingredients.  In the top part of the view I have this:

```
<%= form_for :rec do |f| %>
```

I then list the recipe fields which are displayed correctly, like:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
```

I then try to display the ingredient lines but the code never seems to go into the fields_for section:

first try:

```
<% for ingredient in @recipe.recipe_ingredients %>  
    This prints out three times
    <% fields_for "...", ingredient do |ingredient_form| %>  
      But this never prints out
      <p>  
      Ingredient: <%= ingredient_form.text_field :description %>  
      </p>  
    <% end %>  
  <% end%>
```

I have three empty lines in recipe_ingredients and the for loop seems to iterate three times but the code within fields_for never triggers.

Second try:

```
  <% for recipe_ingredient in @recipe.recipe_ingredients %>
    b

    <% fields_for "...", recipe_ingredient do |recipe_ingredient| %>
      Rec: <%= recipe_ingredient.text_field :description %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Third try (based on the answer here):

```
<% form_for :recipe do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for ingredients do |ingredient_form| %>  
      <p>  
      Ingredient: <%= ingredient_form.text_field :description %>  
      </p>  
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch it up to

```
<% form_for :recipe do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_form| %>  
      <p>  
      Ingredient: <%= ingredient_form.text_field :description %>  
      </p>  
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have this above:
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>

When I try your code I get the following error:
undefined local variable or method `ingredients' for #<#<Class:0x00000101e9fd20>:0x00000101e9b900>

Comment: @gugguson -- I had "ingredients" but meant ":ingredients" -- the symbol ingredients will tell the form_for(recipe) to call the ingredients array.

Comment: Great - that worked.  Thank you for your help.
Small question:  How would I go about using it in the Show view?

Comment: In the show, you'd do <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient|%> <%= ingredient.description%><br/><% end %>

Answer (score 27):

You should use **<%=** instead of <% when using **form_for** and **fields_for**

The correct code should look like this:

```
<%= form_for :recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_form| %>  
      <p>  
      Ingredient: <%= ingredient_form.text_field :description %>  
      </p>  
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why my code wasn't working. It was only when I put <%= that it started working. So thanks! :)

Comment: However, in Rails 2, you should not use the equals sign. I can't find the source from Rails' documentation, but here are some links to demonstrate others who ran into this for Rails 2 http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-using_form_for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459002/getting-fields-for-to-work-with-has-many-relationship