# Getting fields_for to work with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble generating a nested model form.

Here are my models:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scores
    has_many :users, :through => :scores
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :workout
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scores
    has_many :workout, :through => :scores
end
```

In the Workout controller, here's what I have for the new action:

```
def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    3.times { @workout.scores.build }

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @wod }
    end
end
```

However, in the form, when I try fields_for, I don't get anything:

```
<% f.fields_for :scores do |builder| %>
    <p>
        <%= builder.label :score %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :score %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `Wod` and why are you creating that in your Workouts controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out in Rails 3, I need to use <%= fields_for ... %> instead of <% fields_for ... %>.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `Workout` model:

```
attr_accessible :scores_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores
```

If you want to make sure that a score doesn't get built unless is it valid, and that is can be destroyed through the relationship you can expand to:

```
attr_accessible :scores_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores, reject_if: proc { |a| a[:field].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
validates_associated :scores
```

Just switch `:field` with a relevant field that is required for a score to be created.

Comment: Silly me, the issue was using <% fields_for ... %> instead of <%=