# Nested Attributes in Form Not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the 3 Models, that says a Voter has many votes and i'm trying to get the voter to vote on the same form as when the voting object is created but the field in my form isn't showing. 
Here are my models:

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :verification_code, :verified, :votes_attributes
  has_many :votes, :class_name => "Vote"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :voter
  attr_accessible :entry, :voter, :voter_id
end
```

And in my form I have:

```
<%= form_for(@voter) do |f| %>
<% if @voter.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@voter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this voter from being saved:</h2>

<ul>
<% @voter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email_address %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email_address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :verification_code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :verification_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :verified %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :verified %>
  </div>

<div class="field">
      <% f.fields_for :votes do |builder| %>  
        <fieldset>
        <%= builder.label :votes, "Entry" %>
        <%= collection_select(:entry, :entry_id, Entry.all, :id, :email_address, :prompt => 'Please select an Entry') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But the votes field isn't showing. And I can't understand why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting fields\_for to work with has\_many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459002/getting-fields-for-to-work-with-has-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 you need to use:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :votes do |builder| %>
```

This will fix the problem.